# Intersection of Galois extensions with additional algebraic element.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I wasn't really sure what would be an appropriate title for this problem, but the statement is not too complicated.

I take $F/K$ a Galois extension of a field $K$. I take $\theta \in F$. Finally I take $N,N'$ two normal subextensions of $F$, such that $N'(\theta )$ is normal over $N'$. My question is whether the following inclusion is true:

$(N \cap N'(\theta )) \subseteqq (N \cap N')(\theta )$.

Comment: Don't you have that the left hand side is contained in N which in turn is contained in the right hand side?

Comment: @sss89 Why would $N$ be contained in $(N \cap N')(\theta )$? When intersecting with $N'$ there could still be some elements missing regardless of whether we adjoin $\theta$.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't paying enough attention.